Google Earth Engine - Code won't run past September 2020
I have some code which can be found here. It calculates an environmental stress index coral reef regions using Google Earth Engine.
I've tried to calculate some new data recently but I realised it won't run past September 2020. When I try it now get's this error
ImageCollection (Error)
Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required

The product it calls (NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI) is still available past that date. May be the name of something the code is looking for in the metadata has been changed after that date, but I've search and searched and I can't figure out what.
Otherwise I cannot figure out why the code runs and outputs up to but not past September 2020.
I think I have isolated it to lines 155-177 in the code, which is below.
var SSTA_7d =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      DOY.map(function(d) {
      d = ee.Number(d);
      var SSTA_date = series_daily
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7),'day_of_year'));
                      
      var img_last = ee.Image(SSTA_date.sort('system:time_start',true).first());
      var size = SSTA_date.size();

      var SSTA_filtered_7d = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(size.eq(0),
                                            ee.Image.constant(0).toFloat(),
                                            ee.Image(series_daily
                                            .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(d, d.add(7), 'day_of_year'))
                                            .mean()
                                            )));
      
      return SSTA_filtered_7d
              .set('DOY', d)
              .set('system:time_start', img_last.get('system:time_start'));

  })
  .flatten()
);


Hi there! To help you more effectively, could you specify the section of the code where you're encountering the error? Sharing the entire code block without pointing out specific areas can make it difficult to pinpoint the issue. Also, the assets you've imported aren't accessible, which makes debugging challenging because the code can't run without those imports. Providing these details will enable better assistance.

Thanks. I have added the lines of the code I think is causing the error. I have added access to the assets as well by ticking the 'anyone can read' box. I believe that should allow you access.
